# Change select options in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have the following test code:

```
ID = {
   CreatedBy: { id: 'createdBy' },
   ModifiedBy: { id: 'modifiedBy' }
}

Profile = {
   All: { text: 'All', val: 0 },
   Sys: { text: 'system_system@system.com', val: 1 },
   Test: { text: 'test_user@live.com', val: 2 }
}

changeSelect(dataId: EnumElement[], params: UserEnum[]) {
   dataId.forEach((data) => {
      params.forEach((elem) => {
         var label = data.id+ ' - Check option changed to - ' + elem.text;
         it(label, () => {
               return element(by.xpath('//select[@id="' + data.id + '"]/option[@value = "' + elem.val + '"]')).click();
         });
    });
}
```

In my test I am calling the changeSelect() function with parameters like such:

```
changeSelect([ID.CreatedBy, ID.ModifiedBy], [Profile.Sys, Profile.Test]);
```

As expected my changeSelect() function will output:

```
createdBy - Check option changed to - system_system@system.com
createdBy - Check option changed to - test_user@live.com
modifiedBy - Check option changed to - system_system@system.com
modifiedBy - Check option changed to - test_user@live.com
```

But this is not the output that I want. How can I tweak my loop to achieved the output below?

```
createdBy - Check option changed to - system_system@system.com
modifiedBy - Check option changed to - test_user@live.com
```

Comment: Do you want to change your loop, or the way you call it? Try calling it like this: `changeSelect([ID.CreatedBy], [Profile.Sys]);changeSelect([ID. ModifiedBy], [Profile. Test]);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple for?

```
changeSelect(dataId, params) {
    for(i = 0; i < dataId.length; i++){
        var data = dataId[i];
        var elem = params[i];
        var label = data.id + ' - Check option changed to - ' + elem.text;
        it(label, () => {
            return element(by.xpath('//select[@id="' + data.id + '"]/option[@value = "' + elem.val + '"]')).click();
        }
    }
}
```